# What size should the Layout height's that contains a SMART_BANNER be?

Tags: java, android, layout, admob

So I have a RelativeLayout that contains the SMART_BANNER. Should it has a minimum height so that it can display many banner sizes? I don´t know what size should I put as layout height..

Relative Layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/id_ad_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Banner:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/ad_view_banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                app:adUnitId="@string/id_of_banner">

            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Screen width x 32|50|90 as u can see in [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#banner_sizes)

Comment: @VishalBeep so I have put in RelativeLayout  android:layout_height="100dp", is that OK?

Comment: Why don't you use `wrap_content` for your `RelativeLayout `?

Comment: Why should I use wrap_content for your RelativeLayout ? What is the problem of using what I am using?